# Idiomatic translation of "Debug"

Tags: лексикон, перевод, информатика

Is there a proper idiomatic translation of "Debug" into the Russian Language? I am not sure about "наладка программы", which I found on [en.bab.la](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-russian/debug)

Comment: Обезжучиваем программы! :)

Comment: The only traditional and widely used form is "отладка" (and "отладчик" for 'debugger'), for a few decades. But there are new flows. The book "Наука отладки" (http://www.books.ru/books/nauka-otladki-86536/) carries "отладка" on the cover but intentionally uses "наладка" inside through the whole text. I don't have English original (http://www.amazon.com/The-Science-Debugging-Matt-Telles/dp/1576109178) so I can't determine whether it's affected by the latter. And, "наладка" isn't accepted by the community.

Comment: Наладка is usually used for hardware tuning.

Comment: @Artemix after some rethinking I would prefer "наладка" for a particular system installation and configuring, but "отладка" for fixing of a program or component "in vitro".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you mean the software context, then it's ***отла́дка***:

> *отла́дка програ́ммы* (debugging of a program)
>   *отла́живать програ́мму* (to debug a program)
>   *отла́дчик* (debugger)

But sometimes speak on slang (Runglush):

> *дебаг*
>   *дебажить*
>   *дебаггер*

For example: *Вчера весь вечер **дебажил** программу.*

Comment: отладка, поиск ошибок в программе.

Comment: +1 Also, debugger = отладчик, I think you should include that in your answer too

Comment: I have also heard "дебужить" as a slang verb for debug.

Comment: I would not include this slang here. It is not Russian.

Comment: I agree. The question was about translation, not about the words used.